# Study design will have missing data dependent on conditions. Is it possible to get an omnibus statistic and determine relative outcome prevalence?

Tags: r, experiment-design, proportion, ab-test, choice-modeling

First, here is the hypothetical data frame in R.

```
Version <- rep(c("AB","AC","BC"),each = 300)
OutcomeAB <- sample(c("A","B"), size = 300, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.6,.4))
OutcomeAC <- sample(c("A","C"), size = 300, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.4,.6))
OutcomeBC <- sample(c("B","C"), size = 300, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.7,.3))
Outcome <- c(OutcomeAB, OutcomeAC, OutcomeBC)
df <- as.data.frame(Version, Outcome)
```

Version is which flight users are part of. Each flight will let them select between 2 of 3 possible options (outcomes A,B,C). I want to say which outcome is most preferred.

Okay, so let's look at the data:

```
table(Version, Outcome)
```

You will notice that the one diagonal is 0. This is because each version only exposes participants to 2 of the 3 options/outcomes.

```
           Outcome
Version   A   B   C
      AB 183 117   0
      AC 115   0 185
      BC   0 206  94
```

Here is the crux of the problem. If you do pairwise comparisons, you realize if you're interested what outcome is chosen by participants most you'll get something that feels paradoxical:

1. A > B in occurrence
2. A < C in occurrence
3. C > B in occurrence

Part of me wants to account for the version on this, but that doesn't make sense or resolve the issue.

```
mod <- glm(Outcome ~ Version,data = df, family = "binomial")
```

I can do tests for independence, but I KNOW there are dependencies, so I don't know how to interpret the findings.

```
proptab <- prop.table(table(Version, Outcome))
summary(proptab)
```

Or...

```
library(MASS)
mytable <- xtabs(~Version+Outcome, data=df) 
loglm(~Version+Outcome, mytable)
```

Visualizing helps a bit:

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(rawtab, shade=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

Should I just stick to pairwise comparisons to determine which outcome is most likely to chosen (and live with things that will feel paradoxical)? This feels similar to maxdiff and latin-squares type problems, but I didn't jump down that rabbit hole (I would need to start). How do I determine which outcome is most likely to be chosen based on the data above?

Suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to test or find out from your data?  The only question you articulate is "how do I determine which outcome is most likely?," but what exactly does that mean? In what sense are your data a sample of some process or population and why should information about `Version` affect your estimates of the frequencies of the three values of `Outcome`?

Comment: Version is more of a covariate. It shouldn't have an effect for theoretical reasons, but I think I would want to account for it. I really want to know if I should just do pairwise comparisons to try to understand the relative prevalence of outcomes: A > B > C? A = B = C? To be honest, your catching me here tripping on the question because I haven't encountered this experimental design before and I'm trying to understand which option (outcome) are most interested in. It is entirely possible that C outperforms A and underperforms B, but A over performs B, which is logically weird. See new table.